# How to run custom code to parse a string in serverless.yaml?

Tags: serverless-framework

I am using the fantastic tool serverless and the `useDotenv: true` config.

I am loading .env file like:

```
app_url: https:/www.example.com
```

and can use it perfectly fine by referring to it `${env:app_url}`

Now I don't want to use this variable but extract only the host out of this value something like `extractHost(${env:app_url})`

Can I declare nodejs code inside serverless.yaml to run later or make some custom extension to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do it by writing custom variable resolvers in a plugin as described here: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/plugins/custom-variables

Great example of a plugin that does just that can be found here: https://github.com/whardier/serverless-plugin-powertools